# Запрет на ввод символов в поле

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно следующее:
1 - пользователь вводит информацию в форму
2 - js проверяет символы, которые ввел пользователь и выводит предупреждение о неверном заполнении формы, если там присутствуют не английские буквы и/или не цифры, то есть, любой другой символ за исключением английских букв и цифр. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем просто и под данную конкретную ситуацию

```js
var button = document.getElementById('b');
  button.onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('i').value;
    if(!text.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)){
      //alert('error');
      document.getElementById('p').innerHTML='Поле должно содержать английские буквы и цифры';
    }
  }
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<input type="text" id="i">
<button id="b">Ввод</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Enter digits and latinicks symbols">
<button>Ввод</button>
</form>
```

можно и без js

Comment: Само регулярное выражение можно подобрать более подходящее под конкретный случай

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярки

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('input change', function(){
 var val = $(this).val();
 $(this).val(val.replace(/[\W_]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
```

С учётом пожеланий к подчёркиванию.

Comment: `\W` захватывает символ подчёркивания, так что, думаю, это не совсем то, что нужно

Comment: А по аналогии регулярку ни как не доработать?
 `$(this).val(val.replace(/[\W_]/g, ''));`